# How remove asterisks in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Windows 10
Emacs 26.1

Here example of my org file with many inner items
[image]

In my opinion it does not look very comfortable. 
I think asterisks make "noise". Is it possible to remove asterisks?

Comment: Not removing but hiding is possible by setting `org-hide-leading-stars` to t. See the doc of that variable. It cal also be customized. You can set it on a per-buffer basis with `#+STARTUP: hidestars` or `#+STARTUP: showstars`. Also have a look at [`org-indent-mode`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-view.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several possibilities are exposed in the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Clean-View.html#Clean-View).  The first is to use `org-indent-mode`.

> Org provides an alternate stars and indentation scheme,
> as shown on the right in the following table.  It uses only one star and
> indents text to line with the heading:

> ```
> * Top level headline             |    * Top level headline
> ```

```
** Second level                  |      * Second level
*** 3rd level                    |        * 3rd level
some text                        |          some text
*** 3rd level                    |        * 3rd level
more text                        |          more text
* Another top level headline     |    * Another top level headline
```

> To turn this mode on, use the minor mode, ‘org-indent-mode’.  Text
> lines that are not headlines are prefixed with spaces to vertically
> align with the headline text(1)

If you don't want the text to be indented you can just configure the variable `org-hide-leading-stars`

> Org can make leading stars invisible.  For global preference,
> configure the variable ‘org-hide-leading-stars’.  For per-file
> preference, use these file ‘#+STARTUP’ options:

> ```
>       #+STARTUP: hidestars
> ```

```
      #+STARTUP: showstars
```

> ```
>  With stars hidden, the tree is shown as:
> ```

> ```
>      * Top level headline
> ```

```
       * Second level
        * 3rd level
        ...
```

If you had previously set `#+STARTUP: indent` you may need to reset with `C-c C-c` with the cursor on the`#+STARTUP` line (or any other keyword line).

Comment: If you had previously set `#+STARTUP: indent` you may need to reset with `M-x org-mode`

Comment: @rofrol It seems to me it is sufficient to type `C-c C-c` on the `#+STARTUP:` line after having edited it to the chosen value (`indent`, `showstars` or `hidestars`.)  Please do correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Yeah, works. But I needed to type`C-c C-c` twice after changing from indent to hidestars.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the asterisks for any UTF-8 character using [org-bullets-mode](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets).

Just download `org-bullets` from MELPA repository and add the following into your init file:

```
(require 'org-bullets)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (org-bullets-mode 1)))
```

If you don't like default org-bullet symbols, you can set yours as follows:

```
(setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("✙" "♱" "♰" "☥" "✞" "✟" "✝" "†" "✠" "✚" "✜" "✛" "✢" "✣" "✤" "✥"))
```

**Since you want to remove the "noise", the cleanest option is to set bullet symbols to [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm).**

```
(setq org-bullets-bullet-list '("\u200b"))
```

You can find [other bullet symbols sets here](https://zhangda.wordpress.com/2016/02/15/configurations-for-beautifying-emacs-org-mode/).

**Note:** some Windows users have reported rendering issues of unicode, [the solution seems to be here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47483/org-mode-bullets).