# Can't hide leading stars on selected row in org mode

Tags: org-mode

Emacs 26.3

[image]

or this

[image]

As you can see it shows leading stars on selected row.

I want to hide them. I try this:

```
'(org-hide-leading-stars t)
```

But it does not help: stars are not hidden.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How remove asterisks in org mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53445/how-remove-asterisks-in-org-mode)

Answer (score 0):

```
#+STARTUP: hidestars
```

You may need to reset with `M-x org-mode`.